# possible unintended reference comparison to get a value comparison when using SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, combobox, sqldatareader, selectedindexchanged

To Select the `company_name` ,`date_of_mfg` ,`date_of_exp` of a medicine,  first         `medicine_name` is selected and based on its `SelectedIndexchanged` event,I use the following code:

```
     private void combomedicine_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        combocompany.Items.Clear();
        string str = "select med_name,mnf_name from  tbl_mdcnentry";
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = str;
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {


            if (combomedicine.SelectedItem.ToString() == reader.GetValue(0).ToString())
            {
                combocompany.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
                break;
            }

        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

On debugging,the line `if (combomedicine.SelectedItem.ToString()`
                       `== reader.GetValue(0).ToString())` warns :`Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type string`  (though i already casted) and produces no output on selecting new item from drop down.

I've searched and the solution suggested everywhere is to add `ToString()` which still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparing strings I prefer to use [string.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can provide a Comparision type, which I suggest to try using an InvariantCultureIgnoreCase to avoid casing problems.

Have you debug and checked that the two strings are actually the same?

Also, consider moving your data access code away from the UI, it will make easier to maintain and understand your code in the long term.

EDIT: also its a better practise to encapsulate the DataReader in an using block:

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (string.Equals(combomedicine.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
                          reader.GetValue(0).ToString(), 
                          StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        {
            combocompany.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you debug are the contents of combomedicine.SelectedItem.ToString() and reader.GetValue(0).ToString() really the same? Maybe you are comparing the wrong things.

Comment: Yes,they both have the same values!

Comment: Upvoted for the use of `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` but here the 'case' is not an issue.Accepted for introducing `string.Equals` though i arrived at solution too!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i did after going through [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson04).

```
 private void combomedicine_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        combocompany.Items.Clear();
        GetAutoCombobox_filled();
    }

  //Helper method
    public void GetAutoCombobox_filled()
    {

        // int select_item;
        string str = "select med_name,mnf_name,mfg_date,exp_date from  tbl_mdcnentry";
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = str;
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {


            if (combomedicine.SelectedItem.ToString() == (string)reader["med_name"])
            {
                combocompany.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
                dateTimePicker2.Text=reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                dateTimePicker3.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                break;
            }

        }
        reader.Close();


    }
```